# Is GlusterFS suitable for intermittent connections

Tags: replication, glusterfs

I'm a bit paranoid about data loss, and have a Laptop running DRBD (on Ubuntu) so that when I'm at home my data is RAIDED across the network in real time - and if take my laptop out, data is synced on my return.   I do, however, have some issues related to encryption on top of the DRBD device and not easily being able to automatically mount the filesystem during bootup.

As I'm rebuilding my Laptop, I'm wondering if I can do something similar using GlusterFS - ie Does GlusterFS automatically and seamlessly handle network disconnects and reconnects and then replicate the data in the background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not - I tried this and Glusterfs does not like it at all if its asked to connect (even on localhost) when the remote server is unavailable - and when the localhost box is a full replica.

Its not entirely clear to me why this is happening, and maybe things will improve - I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 btw.